# Facebook app link not redirecting to Facebook canvas page

Tags: php, facebook

Launching my canvas page Facebook app is driving me crazy. When I posted it's link (http://apps.facebook.com/digitalhitcelebrity) to a fan page wall the FB "attach link" button grabbed the app's callback url (http://www.digitalhit.com/celebotd) instead.

The strangeness occurs here: if you go to the the callback url when NOT logged in it redirects you properly to the canvas page. If you go to that url when you ARE logged in you don't get redirected and the page is not framed by the Facebook branding.

Using the new php-sdk. Any ideas?

Comment: Callback url is not supposed to automatically redirect you to the facebook app, unless you programmed this yourself. If facebook grabbed the wrong link, well it's a facebook bug then.

Comment: It's odd though that the callback url redirects to the canvas page if the user is NOT logged in but doesn't if they ARE.

Comment: could you post your app settings, minus the sensitive info?